# How parse this excel?

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel file, i have to parse to list of objects:
excel:
[excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stvhc.png)

my pojo:

my service:

```
public List<RegisterModel> parse(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());
        Sheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        List<RegisterModel> registerModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        RegisterModel registerModel = new RegisterModel();
        for (int i = 3; i < worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {

            Row row = worksheet.getRow(i);
            String headers = String.valueOf(row.getCell(0));
            String values = String.valueOf(row.getCell(1));

            if (headers.equals("OPERDAY")){
                registerModel.setDate(values);
            }
            if (headers.equals("SUIP")){
                registerModel.setSuip(values);
            }
            if (headers.equals("STATE")){
                registerModel.setSuip(values);
            }
            if (headers.equals("NOM_OPER")){
                registerModel.setTransactionID(values);
            }
            registerModelList.add(registerModel);

        }
        System.out.println(registerModelList);
        return registerModelList;
    }
```

but it is not works(

result: values are duplicate

[RegisterModel(date=2022-03-01T23:48:47, suip=Проведён, state=null, transactionID=1888314188),

RegisterModel(date=2022-03-01T23:48:47, suip=Проведён, state=null, transactionID=1888314188),

RegisterModel(date=2022-03-01T23:48:47, suip=Проведён, state=null, transactionID=1888314188)]

Comment: "but it is not works", are you getting any error?

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Have you checked what the value of `str` is to make sure that the correct data is selected? How does your code tell the difference between the NOM_ORDER and the SUIP rows and work out which one is the TransactionID? Please provide more details, and add some debugging so that you can see what is being processed.

Comment: @sorifiend edited)

Comment: Oh, just move this line `RegisterModel registerModel = new RegisterModel();` inside your `for` loop. Otherwise, you just keep overwriting and adding the same object to your list over and over.

Comment: @sorifiend if I will move object to inside `for` it will write only one value to ogject. i need to write all values(OPERDAY, SUIP,STATE ,NOM_OPER)  to object, after that add to `List`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by only creating a single instance of `registerModel` outside of your `for` loop. You just keep editing that object over and over instead of creating new instances of it. The way to solve this is to create a new instance of `registerModel` every time a previous object is completed or before a new object is started.

There are multiple ways to achieve this by using nested loops or incrimenting your `for` loop by 5 at a time (rows in your order) and specifically keeping track of where items are at. However, if we assume that the last bit of data in an order is the "NOM_OPER" row then we can do the following quick and easy solution.

This is the code that has been changed:

```
    if (headers.equals("NOM_OPER")){
        registerModel.setTransactionID(values);

        //Now that the object is complete we can add it to the list (moved here from below)
        registerModelList.add(registerModel);

        //The lastly we NEED to create a new instance of registerModel for the next order to use
        registerModel = new RegisterModel();
    }
    //Remove the below line after the if statements.
    //You should only add the model to the list once the object is complete. Don't add it on every row.
    //registerModelList.add(registerModel);
```

And the complete method looks like this:

```
public List<RegisterModel> parse(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());
    Sheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    List<RegisterModel> registerModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    RegisterModel registerModel = new RegisterModel();
    for (int i = 3; i < worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        Row row = worksheet.getRow(i);
        String headers = String.valueOf(row.getCell(0));
        String values = String.valueOf(row.getCell(1));

        if (headers.equals("OPERDAY")){
            registerModel.setDate(values);
        }
        if (headers.equals("SUIP")){
            registerModel.setSuip(values);
        }
        if (headers.equals("STATE")){
            registerModel.setSuip(values);
        }
        if (headers.equals("NOM_OPER")){
            registerModel.setTransactionID(values);

            //Now that the object is complete we can add it to the list (moved here from below)
            registerModelList.add(registerModel);

            //The lastly we NEED to create a new instance of registerModel for the next order to use
            registerModel = new RegisterModel();
        }
        //Remove the below line after the if statements.
        //You should only add the model to the list once the object is complete. Don't add it on every row.
        //registerModelList.add(registerModel);

    }
    System.out.println(registerModelList);
    return registerModelList;
}
```